# how to make my maps activity as MVC architecture in android app java?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, model-view-controller

I don't understand how to implement MVC (Model - View - Controller) pattern within an android application.

Could someone please advise me how to divide my code according to MVC pattern.

I'm working with google maps api. I've read some articles with examples but it would help me to see on my real example. I would be really glad if someone could explain

My MapsActivity class is included below.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {

    private RequestQueue queue;
    private View mapView;
    private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    public LatLng pnt;
    private GoogleMap mMap;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        assert mapFragment != null;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        setUpMap();
    }

    public void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);

        LatLng spb = new LatLng(59.93, 30.36);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(spb).title("me"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(spb));

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }

    public void onArrowClick(View view) {

    }


    public void getBounds() {
        LatLngBounds b = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
        Toast.makeText(this, b.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void OnAddMarkClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SendForm.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void getRequest() {
//sending request here to place marks according to location
        String url ="";
        
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
                            JSONArray points = data.getJSONArray("points");
                            for (int i = 0; i < points.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject point = points.getJSONObject(i);
                                String id = point.getString("pointId");
                                String title = point.getString("title");
                                String geom = point.getString("geom");
                                geom = geom.replaceAll(("[\\[\\](){}]"),"");
                                geom = geom.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");

                                String[] coord = geom.split(" ");

                                pnt = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(coord[1]), Double.parseDouble(coord[0]));

                                Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pnt).title("").
                                        icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mark)));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        getRequest();
    }

   }
```

Comment: Why MVC? That's not standard practice in Android. / "i've read some articles with examples" - what did you learn from those articles? What have you tried? What isn't working? What specifically don't you understand? You need to ask focused, detailed questions. It's unlikely anyone will come through to rewrite your code for you.